What is the correct article before "/s/ sound"?

There is ( a - an - the - no article ) /s/ sound in the word "city".

What's the correct choice here?
I thought it is "a" as we are talking here about the sound sss and its pronunciation here begins with consonant but when I geogled it, I found it written " an /s/ sound.

Where did you see it? Certainly here's a use of "a city". I can find "Ya'an city" in an article about China, but I think you have failed to allow for the possibility that not everybody is perfect all the time.

The upvotes for two different answers can be confusing for learners trying to determine the correct choice. If this is an examination question, you must choose from the given options. If none of them seem correct, you have to leave the question unanswered. Examiners are not looking for other alternatives.

Quite simply, because 's' is pronounced 'ess'. It sounds as though it begins with a vowel, so we use 'an' before it.

Thanks but isn't the sound here pronounced "sss"  as in snake not "es" so it's a sss sound not an sss sound ? we don't say the name of the letter here.

No, the 'name' of the sound, as of the letter, is 'ess' (it's usual to add a vowel sound when saying a consonant, because that's easier).

The confusion is understandable - like Kate says, when an English speaker reads /s/ or /h/, etc , we are likely to say 'ess' or 'aitch' rather than the sounds 'sss' or 'huh'. On the other hand, we would more likely say 'chuh' if we read "a /ch/ sound" instead of saying 'see-aitch'.

At one time, it was a big deal whether you said "a hotel" or "an hotel"...

@JeremyBoden - Yes, because hotel was regarded as a French loanword and pronounced with a silent 'h', while the older word hostel(ry) wasn't.

@HorusKol Maybe marginally more than otherwise, but it's still very common to say "see-aitch sound" IME.

It does in fact begin with a vowel sound. You can't even say a consonant without one...

@Lambie Can't say a consonant sound without a vowel. Mm hmm. Sure.

@Jafe - As I said in my earlier comment, it's easier and clearer to add a vowel sound when speaking about the sound of a consonant.

@Jafe Yes, of course. Please say in English, the letter T. You are obliged to say: tea/tee, for example. This:  /ē// Try any other consonant. All of them can only be pronounced as a single letter  in association with a vowel sound.

Or: if you say the letter s, it's ess as in lioness, as Kate states.

Oh, I agree with this answer and would pronounce it as ess in the sentence written. Just pointing out that it's a misconception that you can't say a consonant without an accompanying vowel sound in English. Native speakers have no problem pronouncing things like hmm, psst, shh etc.

@Jafe - That's why I specified "when speaking about the sound of a consonant", as distinct from making an inarticulate sound.

@Jafe Hmm is not a "spoken word", psst has a vowel sound, so does shh=sha.

It is impossible to tell from the written text how the non-word  "/s/" would be pronounced in speech.
You could say  "/ei s saund in ðə wərd siti/"
You could say "an es saund in ðə wə:rd siti/"
And so it is impossible to say from the written text alone which form of the article would be used.
This creates no practical problem.
For the sake of the test, assume that /s/ is read "es" and so "an /s/"

A similar puzzle:

What is the correct article? "(A/an) unionised one would cause a problem."

Answer: impossible to say.  The word "unionised" can mean "formed into a union  (a unionised one), or it can mean "not ionised" (an unionised one).  There is insufficient context to decide which meaning, and hence decide on the correct article.

"And so it is impossible to say from the written text alone which form of the article would be used." Are you saying this rule doesn't exist -  Acronyms beginning with a consonant sound use “a.” Acronyms beginning with a vowel sound use “an.”.

@JamesMathai No, they're saying that it's impossible to say from the written text alone whether the phrase "/s/ sound" is to be pronounced as to begin with a consonant sound or with a vowel sound. Both options are plausible, since the notation /s/ could be pronounced as the very sound it denotes (a consonant), or as the name of the letter it contains (which starts with a vowel sound).

the rule for acronyms is correct, but "/s/ isn't an acronym.  It is a representation of a phoneme, and an ipa character.  There's more than one way to indicate this in speech.  Probably you would use the name of the related English letter: "S" (or ess) or you could say "unvoiced dental fricative" or you could say "sss"

"A uniunionised [..]" does not exist. The meaning of the noun holds no influence.

@paddotk 'belonging to a union' begins with a /j/, 'not having a net electric charge' begins with a vowel /ʌ/. "a union", "a unionized labor force", "an unionized carbon atom"

It's also the case that it can depend on the speaker. It's becoming less and less common but a speaker who doesn't pronounce the 'h' sound at the beginning of a word should use 'an' and one that does should use 'a' unless they add a different consonant (e.g. a New Yorker might pronounce human like 'yuuman'.)  Sometimes people get confused and say 'an historical' event even though they voice the 'h' because they read an old book or something.

@Kaia Yes but the word ununionized does not begin with the /j/ sound. Notice the difference between unionized and ununionized.

@paddotk I guess I'm not understanding why 'ununionized' is in discussion at all?

@Kaia Nevermind that, I misread.

@paddotk so you misread two answers and downvoted at least one of them. You can retract a downvote–not the same as casting an upvote– if in the meantime the answer was edited.

The OP, @O A, should realise that each letter in the English alphabet is a distinctive “word". For example, the letter L is called "el", M is called "em", N is "en", and S is "ess"  (pronounced /ˈɛs/). When these individual letters appear in words their pronunciation may change, the letter S at the end of a word is not always pronounced “sss” /s/ e.g.

ladies /ˈlā-dēz/
glasses /glɑ́ːsɪz/ or /ˈɡlæsəz/
wash /wɒʃ/
fox /fɒks/  (the letter X is called ex and is pronounced /ˈɛks/)

As we know, the letter F in the alphabet is ef (pronounced /ˈɛf/) but there are also combinations of letters which make the same sound, e.g. ph in "alphabet" pronounced /ˈalfəbɛt/; elephant  pronounced either /ˈɛlᵻf(ə)nt/) or (/ˈɛləfənt/); gh in “cough” (kɒf), and in “enough” (/ɪˈnʌf/ or /ᵻˈnəf/). So, we might say the letters f, ph, and gh often make an f sound (or) an /ˈɛf/ sound.
The letters in FBI are spoken individually: eff+bee+eye //ˈɛf.biː.aɪ/

The first letter in FBI begins with an F.

We can also use letters to describe objects, shapes, or manoeuvres.

Knights move in an L-shape and can "jump" over pieces. [chess]
BUT
You're not allowed to make a U turn here.

Although the letter U is a vowel, its pronunciation begins with a consonant sound "y", so we need to use "a".
In the case of city, pronounced /ˈsɪti/, we can say

The first letter of city begins with an s [an ess] sound.
The first letter of city is pronounced /s/.


This does not answer the question.

@paddotk Why? I explained that S has a given name in the alphabet, it is not only a phonemic sound, i.e. "es". Its name begins with a vowel sound so the indefinite article "an" is used.  I also gave other letters of the alphabet whose names begin with the vowel "e"; e.g. ef, el, em and ex thereby implying that "an S" is the not the exception, and is not an isolated case. But I did forget to add "en" for N. I even gave an example where the vowel, U, is pronounced yu, which begins with a consonant sound, so the article is "a" used when we talk about U-turn.

It was the point that James K was making with unionised, un has two different pronunciations: Union and UNderstand. (I've just seen your comments below his answer). What is missing from this answer, how can I improve it?

I'm sorry, it was kinda late when I answered and I see now that you do mention it should be 'a sound'. I inadvertedly read past it. Also with 'unionized' which I read as 'ununionized', although the fact remains that the meaning of a noun makes no difference when i comes to a/an.

@paddotk Thank you for responding, I'm relieved you see I did answer the question. Might you consider retracting your downvote?

@paddotk it's not the meaning that matters per se, it's the pronunciation of the letter "u" that dictates whether the indefinite article an or a is used, e.g.  unionized,  briefly, to reverse an ionized molecule e.g. an unionized atom. The act of forming a union is called unionized/unionised // ˈjuːnɪənʌɪzd //

E.g. In chemistry, the creation of new molecules often begins by breaking bonds in an unionized molecule, which generates two ionized molecules or atoms.

Yes, that's my point indeed.

I.Rule for using the indefinite article:.
OP's query:

There is ( a - an - the - no article ) /s/sound in the word "city". What's the correct choice here?

The Google search answer is correct:
There is an "s" sound in the word "city".
Here is the explanation:
Rule:.
"a" should be used before a word that begins with a  consonant sound and "an" should be used with a word that begins with a vowel sound.
II. A or an before acronyms..

But remember that even the spoken form of a consonant can begin with a vowel sound (e.g., [em] for M, [aitch] for H).
Acronyms beginning with a consonant sound use “a.” Acronyms beginning with a vowel sound use “an.”.

Examples:

1. "She works as an FBI agent, specializing in cybercrime."
"The new TV requires an HDMI cable for high-definition video."
*"The doctor ordered an MRI to examine the patient's injured knee.""
"She holds an MBA degree from a prestigious business school."
"The charity is registered as an NGO, focusing on environmental conservation."
*"She sent me an SMS to confirm our meeting time.""


Thanks but isn't the sound here pronounced "sss"  as in snake not "es" so it's a sss sound not an sss sound ? we don't say the name of the letter here.

@OA  Yes "sound" is pronounced as "snake". But we have to consider the sound of the letter "s" (es). Similarly F, N, M, H will have "an". An sms, An MBA degree.

@OA It is "a snake" but an sms, an SAT prep course, an "s" (ess) sound, an "m" (em) sound, an "f" (ef) sound.  It is how we pronounce the letter of the alphabet - a "u" (you) sound.

Of course, where SAT tests are a thing and pronounced as an acronym (/sæt/), it's "a SAT prep course".

I agree with James K, and specifically I think talking about the voiceless alveolar sibilant /s/, I would pronounce it as /s/ and write "a /s/". If I'm saying the letter, I'd say /ˈɛs/ and write "an s".

Remember to add an "s" to "walk", since the noun is singular.
There is a /s/ sound in the word "city"

Wikipedia appears to use a (not an) even when denoting vowels:

From a [sk] or [ks] cluster in southern Romance
...noting that a /uː/ ~ /ʊ/

This breaks the rules
I think switching from English to IPA will always have a bit of weirdness, and that's OK.
If I write or say,

"How do you say «¿qué tal?» in English?"

There's going to be a bit of weirdness because I have to make compromises between English and Spanish. In writing, do I put a ¿? Do I use « or " for the quote? Style guides will have rules, but they aren't entirely consistent and in practice you'll just do whatever seems reasonable. In speech, I'm likely going to briefly pause to "find" my Spanish pronunciation and to make it clear to the listener where the English stopped and the Spanish started.
This is a more niche example, but in LGBT circles it's somewhat common to use a "floppy wrist" gesture to mean "gay, in a somewhat stereotypical 'effeminate' way". And so in speech, you might hear somebody go,

"Oh, you wouldn't get it, it's a [floppy wrist gesture] thing".

There's not really a single word that [floppy wrist gesture] replaces, so you can't apply the starts-with-a-vowel rule, but that's OK because it's switching between spoken English and a gesture.
If you write/say:

There is a /s/ in the word "city"

You're briefly switching from English orthography to IPA orthography. And so if there's still a noticable "break", that's not an issue. The "break" is actually important because it helps signal the switch.

Bravo, Kate! A nice answer.

There is ( a - an - the - no article ) /s/ sound in the word "city".
an /s/ sound, because to say it you need a vowel sound: the  /ɛ/ as in set.
/s/ sound Listen to sound made by the lady in the picture.
